# Поиск максимальной компоненты связности для каждой вершины неориентированного графа

Tags: c++

Мне нужно найти для каждой вершины максимальную компоненту связности, которая образовалась бы при удалении этой вершины.Мой код. Как мне это сделать, например в функции bfs?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
const int MAXV = 50;
bool processed[MAXV + 1];
bool discovered[MAXV + 1];
int parent[MAXV + 1];
struct list
{
    int y;
    list *next;
};
struct graph
{
    list *edges[MAXV + 1];      //списки смежности для каждой вершины 
    int degree[MAXV + 1];       // степень каждой вершины
    int nvertices;              // кол-во вершин
    int nedges;                 //кол-во сторон
    bool directed;              //тип графа
};
void insert_edge(graph *g, int x, int y, bool directed)
{
    list *p = new list;
    p->y = y;
    p->next = g->edges[x];
    g->edges[x] = p;
    g->degree[x] ++;
    if (directed == false)
        insert_edge(g, y, x, true);
    else
        g->nedges++;

}
void initilaize_graph(graph *g, bool directed)
{
    int i;
    g->nvertices = 0;
    g->nedges = 0;
    g->directed = directed;
    for (i = 1; i <= MAXV; i++)
    {
        g->edges[i] = NULL;
        g->degree[i] = 0;

    }
}
void read_graph(graph *g, bool directed, ifstream &f)
{
    int i, m, x, y;
    initilaize_graph(g, directed);
    f >> g->nvertices;
    m = g->nvertices;
    for (i = 1; i < m; i++)
    {
        f >> x >> y;
        insert_edge(g, x, y, directed);
    }
}
void print_graph(graph *g)
{
    int i;
    list *p;
    for (i = 1; i <= g->nvertices; i++)
    {
        printf("%d: ", i);
        p = g->edges[i];
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            printf(" %d", p->y);
            p = p->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void initiliaze_search(graph *g) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= g->nvertices; i++) 
    {
        processed[i] = discovered[i] = false;
        parent[i] = -1;
    }
}
void bfs(graph *g, int start)
{
    queue <int> q;
    int v, y;
    list* p;
    q.push(start);
    discovered[start] = true;
    while (!q.empty()) 
    {
        v = q.front(); q.pop();
        processed[v] = true;
        p = g->edges[v];
        while (p != NULL) 
        {
            y = p->y;
            if (discovered[y] == false) 
            {
                q.push(y);
                discovered[y] = true;
                parent[y] = v;
            }
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
void connected_components(graph *g,ifstream &f) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= g->nvertices; i++) 
    {

        initiliaze_search(g);
        bfs(g, i);


    }
}
int main()
{
    ifstream f("jok.txt");                                       // 6
    if (f) {                                                    // 1 2
        graph *g = new graph;                                   //2 3
        read_graph(g, false, f);                                // 2 5
        print_graph(g);                                         // 3 4
        connected_components(g, f);                             // 3 6
    }                                                           // ответ должен быть 1-5 2-3 3-3 4-5 5-5
    else cout << "Error";
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Не по теме. В функции read_graph происходит смешение понятий количество вершин и количество ребер. Из вашего кода (особенно с циклом от единицы до количества вершин) получается, что ребер в этом графе должно быть **ВСЕГДА** на 1 меньше чем вершин.
Да, с вашими входными данными это работает, но при попытке изменить их количество (например 6 вершин и 6 ребер) будет ошибка.

Не понимаю эту запись "//ответ должен быть 1-5 2-3 3-3 4-5 5-5". Какой смысл цифры до тире и после.

Comment: Первая мысль, которая приходит - это обход в глубину из каждой вершины. Сколько раз нам придется запускать обход в глубину из выбранной вершины - тому и будет равна компонента связности графа, который получится при удалении этой вершины. 
Алгоритм: из вершины X выходит 4 ребра, мы начинаем рекурсивно обходить граф по этим ребрам, помечая вершины, в которых побывали. Если вернулись в первоначальную вершину X, а 3 оставшиеся вершины (на тех 3-х ребрах, куда мы хотим пойти) уже посещены, это означает, что мы достигли их из первого ребра -> компонента связности после удаления вершины не изменится

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятны ответ, который вы дали:

> //ответ должен быть 1-5 2-3 3-3 4-5 5-5

Мне кажется, что в приведенном графе должно получится вот так:
При удалении вершины 1 - компонента связности графа будет равна 1,
2 - 3,
3 - 3,
4 - 1,
5 - 1,
6 - 1.
Возможно у нас с вами разное представления о понятии связности графа)

Вот пример кода:

```
void dfs(const graph* g, int  vertex, bool* vertexVisit)
{
    vertexVisit[vertex] = true;

    for (auto begin = g->edges[vertex]; begin != nullptr; begin = begin->next)
    {
        //y - номер вершины и одновеременно номер в массиве graph::edges ...

        if (vertexVisit[begin->y] == false)     //если мы не посетили эту вершину
        {
            //посещаем!
            dfs(g, begin->y, vertexVisit);
        }
    }
}


//возвращает связность при удалении из графа g вершины vertex
int graphConnectivity(const graph* g, int vertex)
{
    bool vertexVisit[MAXV + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXV + 1; ++i)
        vertexVisit[i] = false;

    vertexVisit[vertex] = true;
    int gConnectivity = 0;

    for (auto begin = g->edges[vertex]; begin != nullptr; begin = begin->next)
    {
        if (vertexVisit[begin->y] == false)
        {
            ++gConnectivity;
            dfs(g, begin->y, vertexVisit);
        }
    }

    return gConnectivity;
}

void calcGraphConnectivity(const graph* g)
{
    std::cout << "\nВывод связности графа при удалении вершин:\n";
    for (int i = 1; i < g->nvertices; ++i)
    {
        std:: cout << "\nУдаляем вершину " << i << ":\tСвязность: \t"<<graphConnectivity(g, i);
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Использовал обход графа в глубину.

Comment: Для ненаправленных графов думаю, что все норм. Для **ориентированных** графов  надо будет внимательно посмотреть.

Comment: Немного не досмотрел вчера - функция graphConnectivity будет работать правильно только если граф g изначально был связным. Для того, чтобы расширить применимость этой функции, необходимо сделать проверку на то, что все вершины были посещены.